# Why does event.getSource() return null for accessibility events that have a related source view?

Tags: android, events, service, accessibility

For the event TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED on android.widget.Button the [event.getSource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord.html#getSource()) method return null. Ideally, this event should have a source attached.

Also from Android API 18 onwards, accessibility events propagated through the [sendAccessibilityEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.html#sendAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)) without a source are not sent. The documentation on which events have sources attached is missing!

Is there any other reliable way to get the [AccessibilityNodeInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html) of the event ? i.e Events which have related views. For Eg [TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) event doesnt have a view as a source

Tried on API 22 and 21

Comment: Is your service receiving _any_ source nodes, e.g. have you specified `android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"` in your service meta-data?

Comment: @alanv Yes I have specified android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" and I am receiving source nodes for few events but for some buttons and imageviews its null. I am looking for an optimal solution where a view related event always has source

Comment: It's an asynchronous call, so if the originating view no longer exists once the call is made (ex. clicking on a button in a dialog) then you're out of luck. This has been fixed in N, where nodes are synchronously created and attached to outgoing events, but there's no reliable way on earlier versions.

Comment: @alanv getsource() doesn't give null sources on android N but I presume the [getRootInActiveWindow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#getRootInActiveWindow()) doesn't work synchronously like the getsource(). Ideally, this should not be asynchronous

Comment: Node access is necessarily asynchronous. You can't hang the UI thread while you wait for every accessibility service to make calls, and you shouldn't send a complete copy of the node hierarchy for every event. That would be horribly slow.

Comment: @alanv Agreed. Maybe, I should explain my objective more clearly. I am trying to get the source node's path from the root. Everything works fine when no window transition occurs as a result of the event. When there is a transition I get inconsistent results. I have detailed my observations in a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940033/how-to-get-a-accessibilitynodeinfos-path-from-the-root-when-a-window-transition)

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem and it is solved by setting notificationTimeout to 100. Sample code is below:

```
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info   = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.packageNames               = new String[]{getApplicationContext().getPackageName()};
    info.eventTypes                 = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    info.feedbackType               = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;
    info.notificationTimeout        = 100;
    info.flags                      = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

Comment: Tkank's a lot. you save me. i face this issue since 2 week ago. @Ecran Baran