# How to Interact with multiple sessions on USSD AlertDialog?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have made an app that can interact with the USSD Dialog but the problem is, I want the app to be able to interact with a series of USSD Dialogs for different services.

It has to collect Response from different USSD Services until the end of the session. I hope it can be understood.

Below are codes for Interacting with any USSD Service with the only first response.

```
if(event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")){
   //         performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
            Log.d(TAG, text);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.times.ussd.action.REFRESH");
            intent.putExtra("message ", text);
            /*AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("1");*/
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();


            if (nodeInfo!= null) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInput = nodeInfo.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                if (nodeInput != null) {
                    bundle.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,"1");
                    nodeInput.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, bundle);
                }
                //nodeInput.refresh();

                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send");
                for(AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list)
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            }
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Null Thing");
        }
```

They are in Service class extending `AccessibilityService`

Comment: If you’re getting null return problems on ‘nodeInput’  find the solution here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833688/why-does-event-getsource-return-null-for-accessibility-events-that-have-a-rela